# How to create migration_version table in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I use MySql and i dropped `migration_versions` table. Now command `doctrine:migrations:migrate` start to execute all migrations from the first one
How can i create and add all migrations to `migration_versions`?

Comment: I just manually added all migration numbers to `migration_versions`, but i'm curious is there command for such situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be done with this command according to the symfony docs:

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --add --all
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#generating-migrations-automatically

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to add them manually (in the mysql console, or PHPMyAdmin), or there is also a console command, that will let you add/delete them all, or a range:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --help
```

> Description:   Manually add and delete migration versions from the
>   version table.
>
> ...
>
> Help:   The doctrine:migrations:version command allows you to manually
>   add, delete or synchronize migration versions from the version table:
>
> ```
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --add
> ```
>
> If you want to delete a version you can use the --delete option:
>
> ```
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --delete
> ```
>
> If you want to synchronize by adding or deleting all migration
>   versions available in the version table you can use the --all option:
>
> ```
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --add --all
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --delete --all
> ```
>
> If you want to synchronize by adding or deleting some range of
>   migration versions available in the version table you can use the
>   --range-from/--range-to option:
>
> ```
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --add --range-from=YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --range-to=YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --delete --range-from=YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --range-to=YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
> ```
>
> You can also execute this command without a warning message which
>   you need to interact with:
>
> ```
>   bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --no-interaction
> ```